# Jenkins failure while installing 'slack Notification' Plugin

Tags: jenkins-plugins, slack

Getting below failure message while trying to install 'slack Notification' Plugin in Jenkins. Here Jenkins is running on AWS ec2 instance and I'm trying with 'install without restart' option.
I checked by logging manually to the ec2 instance and can see that there are few hidden files at path "/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/slack/WEB-INF/lib".

```
jenkins.util.io.CompositeIOException: Unable to delete '/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/slack'. Tried 3 times (of a maximum of 3) waiting 0.1 sec between attempts.
    at jenkins.util.io.PathRemover.forceRemoveRecursive(PathRemover.java:99)
    at hudson.Util.deleteRecursive(Util.java:293)
    at hudson.Util.deleteRecursive(Util.java:282)
    at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.explode(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:476)
    at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.createPluginWrapper(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:175)
    at hudson.PluginManager.dynamicLoad(PluginManager.java:910)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:2052)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob.run(UpdateCenter.java:1740)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.AtmostOneThreadExecutor$Worker.run(AtmostOneThreadExecutor.java:111)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
jenkins.util.io.CompositeIOException: Unable to remove file /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/slack/WEB-INF/lib/.nfs6cd47c1b7f5964f000013284
    at jenkins.util.io.PathRemover.removeOrMakeRemovableThenRemove(PathRemover.java:252)
    at jenkins.util.io.PathRemover.tryRemoveFile(PathRemover.java:205)
    at jenkins.util.io.PathRemover.tryRemoveRecursive(PathRemover.java:216)
    at jenkins.util.io.PathRemover.tryRemoveDirectoryContents(PathRemover.java:226)
    at jenkins.util.io.PathRemover.tryRemoveRecursive(PathRemover.java:215)
    at jenkins.util.io.PathRemover.tryRemoveDirectoryContents(PathRemover.java:226)
    at jenkins.util.io.PathRemover.tryRemoveRecursive(PathRemover.java:215)
    at jenkins.util.io.PathRemover.tryRemoveDirectoryContents(PathRemover.java:226)
    at jenkins.util.io.PathRemover.tryRemoveRecursive(PathRemover.java:215)
    at jenkins.util.io.PathRemover.forceRemoveRecursive(PathRemover.java:96)
    at hudson.Util.deleteRecursive(Util.java:293)
    at hudson.Util.deleteRecursive(Util.java:282)
    at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.explode(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:476)
    at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.createPluginWrapper(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:175)
    at hudson.PluginManager.dynamicLoad(PluginManager.java:910)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:2052)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob.run(UpdateCenter.java:1740)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.AtmostOneThreadExecutor$Worker.run(AtmostOneThreadExecutor.java:111)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/slack/WEB-INF/lib/.nfs6cd47c1b7f5964f000013284: Device or resource busy
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:91)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.implDelete(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:244)
    at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.deleteIfExists(AbstractFileSystemProvider.java:108)
    at java.nio.file.Files.deleteIfExists(Files.java:1165)
    at jenkins.util.io.PathRemover.removeOrMakeRemovableThenRemove(PathRemover.java:237)
    at jenkins.util.io.PathRemover.tryRemoveFile(PathRemover.java:205)
    at jenkins.util.io.PathRemover.tryRemoveRecursive(PathRemover.java:216)
    at jenkins.util.io.PathRemover.tryRemoveDirectoryContents(PathRemover.java:226)
    at jenkins.util.io.PathRemover.tryRemoveRecursive(PathRemover.java:215)
    at jenkins.util.io.PathRemover.tryRemoveDirectoryContents(PathRemover.java:226)
    at jenkins.util.io.PathRemover.tryRemoveRecursive(PathRemover.java:215)
    at jenkins.util.io.PathRemover.tryRemoveDirectoryContents(PathRemover.java:226)
    at jenkins.util.io.PathRemover.tryRemoveRecursive(PathRemover.java:215)
    at jenkins.util.io.PathRemover.forceRemoveRecursive(PathRemover.java:96)
    at hudson.Util.deleteRecursive(Util.java:293)
    at hudson.Util.deleteRecursive(Util.java:282)
    at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.explode(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:476)
    at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.createPluginWrapper(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:175)
    at hudson.PluginManager.dynamicLoad(PluginManager.java:910)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:2052)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob.run(UpdateCenter.java:1740)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.AtmostOneThreadExecutor$Worker.run(AtmostOneThreadExecutor.java:111)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/slack/WEB-INF/lib/.nfs6cd47c1b7f5964f000013284: Device or resource busy
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:91)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.implDelete(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:244)
    at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.deleteIfExists(AbstractFileSystemProvider.java:108)
    at java.nio.file.Files.deleteIfExists(Files.java:1165)
    at jenkins.util.io.PathRemover.removeOrMakeRemovableThenRemove(PathRemover.java:241)
    at jenkins.util.io.PathRemover.tryRemoveFile(PathRemover.java:205)
    at jenkins.util.io.PathRemover.tryRemoveRecursive(PathRemover.java:216)
    at jenkins.util.io.PathRemover.tryRemoveDirectoryContents(PathRemover.java:226)
    at jenkins.util.io.PathRemover.tryRemoveRecursive(PathRemover.java:215)
    at jenkins.util.io.PathRemover.tryRemoveDirectoryContents(PathRemover.java:226)
    at jenkins.util.io.PathRemover.tryRemoveRecursive(PathRemover.java:215)
    at jenkins.util.io.PathRemover.tryRemoveDirectoryContents(PathRemover.java:226)
    at jenkins.util.io.PathRemover.tryRemoveRecursive(PathRemover.java:215)
    at jenkins.util.io.PathRemover.forceRemoveRecursive(PathRemover.java:96)
    at hudson.Util.deleteRecursive(Util.java:293)
    at hudson.Util.deleteRecursive(Util.java:282)
    at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.explode(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:476)
    at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.createPluginWrapper(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:175)
    at hudson.PluginManager.dynamicLoad(PluginManager.java:910)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:2052)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob.run(UpdateCenter.java:1740)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.AtmostOneThreadExecutor$Worker.run(AtmostOneThreadExecutor.java:111)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
jenkins.util.io.CompositeIOException: Unable to remove directory /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/slack with directory contents: [/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/slack/WEB-INF]
    at jenkins.util.io.PathRemover.removeOrMakeRemovableThenRemove(PathRemover.java:250)
    at jenkins.util.io.PathRemover.tryRemoveFile(PathRemover.java:205)
    at jenkins.util.io.PathRemover.tryRemoveRecursive(PathRemover.java:216)
    at jenkins.util.io.PathRemover.forceRemoveRecursive(PathRemover.java:96)
    at hudson.Util.deleteRecursive(Util.java:293)
    at hudson.Util.deleteRecursive(Util.java:282)
    at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.explode(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:476)
    at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.createPluginWrapper(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:175)
    at hudson.PluginManager.dynamicLoad(PluginManager.java:910)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:2052)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob.run(UpdateCenter.java:1740)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.AtmostOneThreadExecutor$Worker.run(AtmostOneThreadExecutor.java:111)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException: /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/slack
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.implDelete(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:242)
    at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.deleteIfExists(AbstractFileSystemProvider.java:108)
    at java.nio.file.Files.deleteIfExists(Files.java:1165)
    at jenkins.util.io.PathRemover.removeOrMakeRemovableThenRemove(PathRemover.java:237)
    at jenkins.util.io.PathRemover.tryRemoveFile(PathRemover.java:205)
    at jenkins.util.io.PathRemover.tryRemoveRecursive(PathRemover.java:216)
    at jenkins.util.io.PathRemover.forceRemoveRecursive(PathRemover.java:96)
    at hudson.Util.deleteRecursive(Util.java:293)
    at hudson.Util.deleteRecursive(Util.java:282)
    at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.explode(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:476)
    at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.createPluginWrapper(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:175)
    at hudson.PluginManager.dynamicLoad(PluginManager.java:910)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:2052)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob.run(UpdateCenter.java:1740)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.AtmostOneThreadExecutor$Worker.run(AtmostOneThreadExecutor.java:111)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException: /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/slack
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.implDelete(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:242)
    at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.deleteIfExists(AbstractFileSystemProvider.java:108)
    at java.nio.file.Files.deleteIfExists(Files.java:1165)
    at jenkins.util.io.PathRemover.removeOrMakeRemovableThenRemove(PathRemover.java:241)
    at jenkins.util.io.PathRemover.tryRemoveFile(PathRemover.java:205)
    at jenkins.util.io.PathRemover.tryRemoveRecursive(PathRemover.java:216)
    at jenkins.util.io.PathRemover.forceRemoveRecursive(PathRemover.java:96)
    at hudson.Util.deleteRecursive(Util.java:293)
    at hudson.Util.deleteRecursive(Util.java:282)
    at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.explode(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:476)
    at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.createPluginWrapper(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:175)
    at hudson.PluginManager.dynamicLoad(PluginManager.java:910)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:2052)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob.run(UpdateCenter.java:1740)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.AtmostOneThreadExecutor$Worker.run(AtmostOneThreadExecutor.java:111)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to dynamically deploy this plugin
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:2056)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob.run(UpdateCenter.java:1740)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.AtmostOneThreadExecutor$Worker.run(AtmostOneThreadExecutor.java:111)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```